# Mapping a code table in BLToolkit

Tags: .net, linq, orm, bltoolkit

In my database, there is one large "code" table with system code look-ups for values used all over the system. Like so:

```
[TableName("code_entries")]                         public class Code {
    [MapField("code_nbr")][PrimaryKey, Identity]    public int Id;
    [MapField("code")]                              public string Value;
}
```

I am new to BLToolkit, and am hoping that there is a concept similar to the static Mappings I have seen, but that will allow me to easily map occurrences of these codes in other tables to their respective values. For instance:

```
    [TableName("person")]                               public class Person {
        [MapField("person_nbr")][PrimaryKey, Identity]  public int Id;
        [MapField("dob")][Nullable]                     public int BirthDate;
        [MapField("eye_color")][Nullable]               public int EyeColorCode;
        [MapField("hair_color")][Nullable]              public int HairColorCode;    
}
```

If EyeColorCode and HairColorCode above map to values in the Codes table, can I create an easy way to map that data within the OR classes and obtain the whole object in a single query?

I'd like to end up with something like:

```
// person.Id = 1
// person.DOB = some date
// person.EyeColor = "Blue"
// person.HairColor = "Brown"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really what you wanted but you could use [Associations](http://bltoolkit.net/Doc.LinqAssociations.ashx)

so you could add this to your Person class

```
[Association(ThisKey="eye_color", OtherKey="code_nbr", CanBeNull=true)]
public Code EyeColor;

[Association(ThisKey="hair_color", OtherKey="code_nbr", CanBeNull=true)]
public Code HairColor;
```

And then do something like

```
from p in db.Person
select new
{
    Id        = p.Id,
    DOB       = p.BirthDate,
    EyeColor  = p.EyeColor.Value,
    HairColor = p.HairColor.Value
};
```

Anyway these seem like the type of codes that almost never change
I usually put these on the client at startup and then fill in the description when I display the data, makes everything a lot easier, and if I can't find an Id then I just
refresh the collection

Comment: We have some such codes that do change enough to do this in data. This is the road I was heading toward, but the problem with this is that it forces me to respecify all the other columns as well in the new object (Id and DOB in your example) and prevents me from using the generated database class (Person) without reconstructing it. These code values are used in so many of our tables, so I wouldn't be able to use the generated classes much at all.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks David. I went with your approach, but modified it slightly to make it a little less painful form me. I added associations to my classes as in your example:

```
[Association(ThisKey = "EyeColorCode", OtherKey = "Id")]    public Code EyeColor { get; set; }
[Association(ThisKey = "HairColorCode", OtherKey = "Id")]   public Code HairColor { get; set; }
```

Then I wrote an extension method. It takes a new object, and merges all the writable properties into the source object. Using this, I don't need to specify every single property in my query, i.e.:

```
from p in db.Person
select p.PropertyUnion(new Person() {
{
    EyeColor  = p.EyeColor,
    HairColor = p.HairColor
};
```

This saves me quite a bit of code for some of my more complex objects, and I think it is more readable. Here is the code for the extension method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Union by retrieving all non-null properties from source parameter and setting those properties on the instance object
/// </summary>
public static T PropertyUnion<T>(this T destination, T source) {
    // Don't copy from a null object
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(destination, null)) {
        return destination;
    }
    // copy properties
    foreach (var property in source.GetType().GetProperties()) {
        if (!property.CanWrite || !property.CanRead)
            continue;
        var match = destination.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name);
        if (!match.CanWrite || !match.CanRead)
            throw new MethodAccessException("Matching property '" + match.Name + "' must allow both read and write operations.");
        var value = property.GetValue(source, null);
        if (value != null && !value.Equals(Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType)))
            match.SetValue(destination, value, null);
    }
    return destination;
}
```

Thanks again for your help!